# Sprite Kit SKS file not working

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Every sks file in every game project has a problem. When I open it, the default color doesn't show. It only shows the previous file with a yellow rectangle. I can't see the nodes I make, or edit them. I can only select them. When I double-click the sks file, the new window says "No Editor" with the yellow rectangle.

Comment: Mines are working fyi. May I ask what version of Xcode you're using, and possibly a screenshot?

Comment: 6.3.2, and I don't have enough reputation to post pictures, but I'll keep describing it as well as I can.

Comment: How are you opening your project? Also how are you creating your SKS files? Are they references or added to your project directory?

Answer (score -1):

If you run your MAC in VMWare, this will happen.

If you upgrade to El-Capital, and install Xcode (from 6.4 to 7.3.1), the Xcode will shutdown if you click to .sks file. And it also shutdown if you create .sks file (in resource).

Sometime, you can open .sks file but it is still nothing there.
The EmitterNodes are no way to exist in VMWare. So, when you run your app in real Iphone, it will make an error CAMetalLayer: calling display has no effect.

I think that is not about the VMWare, all that because of MAC retail that you installed.

The author of MAC retail just make it for everyone to explore OSX, not to do everything with OSX.

And, all applications we know always have some mistakes (that need updates).

Or you wait for new MAC retail

Or do not use .sks file (it will not change your game anymore)

Or buy a MacBook. (or Imac certainly)